# Check input has at least 5 digits while allowing other specific characters

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression (`@"[0-9\. \-\*\(\)]*"`) to allow only certain characters in my string.  I want to know how I can also check that the string contains at least 5 of a subset of those characters namely `[0-9]`.

I could use `@"[0-9]{5,}"` but this wouldn't allow for the other characters I want allowed in the input.

I could use `@"[0-9\. \-\*\(\)]{5,}"` but this would allow inputs that don't contain 5 digits.

I could use `@"[0-9]{5,}[0-9\. \-\*\(\)]*"` but this would require the 5 digits to be at the beginning of the input.

How can I check my input has at least 5 digits while still allowing other characters?

--

For example, I want to match:

`12345` or `123 4-5`

but not

`1 3-5` or `*- 4--*`.

Comment: Do two checks using Regex.

Comment: Similar to @maccettura `bool b = "somestring".Where(char.IsDigit).Count() >= 5;`

Comment: @jdweng You are correct I could do two separate regex checks, I was hoping to have a single regular expression if possible.

Comment: @L.B I deleted my comment, didnt realize the OP also laid out specific special characters.  My solution would not check for that validity

Comment: `^([\. \-\*\(\)]*[0-9][\. \-\*\(\)]*){5,}$` will work with 5 or more digits wrapped around any of the other permitted characters

Comment: @L.B This doesn't verify that only the allowed characters in the regular expression are in the string. I could of course combine this with the regular expression.

Comment: @apokryfos I think this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Dysnomian then do it. easier to maintain then a complex regex

Comment: Not that anyone asked, but I'd much rather see `someInput.DisallowEverything().AllowChar(".").AllowChar("-").etc.RequireDigits(5).Validate();` rather than some hard to read, hard to maintain regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most characters are not special in a character group, so you don't need to escape them.

```
@"[0-9. *()-]{5,}(?<=([. *()-]*[0-9][. *()-]*){5,})";
```

This pattern says find a string of at least five valid characters, then verify the end of that string is preceded by a string of valid characters containing at least 5 digits.

I assume there was a reason your original expression didn't restrict the match to the whole string (locating the phone number?) but if you need the whole string to match:

```
@"^(?=(.*[0-9].*){5})[0-9. *()-]{5,}$"
```

This is somewhat simpler - check the string has at least 5 digits and consists only of valid characters. If you need to include the empty string, it would need a change.

If you are trying to validate phone numbers, both expressions are too simple, as they will accept strings like `((())12--33--44`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that the special characters are not special when in a character group.

To clarify what this patter does, it first checks if there are 5 or more digits, then will check again to verify there are only the allowed characters?

Comment: I had to change the pattern to work properly since you weren't testing the whole string.

Comment: @Dysnomian Sorry, I missed your question :) The first pattern checks for a string of at least five valid characters (probably should be `{5,}` instead of `*`) and then checks there are at least five digits inside that string. The second pattern checks for five (not necessarily consecutive) digit characters and then checks that the whole string consists of valid characters of at least length 5.